# No input fields for the Apple ID Verification for the iMac 10.10.5

Tags: macos, imac, apple-id

Just as my heading says:  There is no input fields for the Apple ID verification codes for the iMac 10.10.5. How in the heck do I get it to come up??

For example, I try to log on to iTunes on my iMac normally, and then it asks for the 6 digit verification code from another device. Okay, no problem. I retrieve it, and when I come back to the Mac, there's no input screen to key in the verification codes. It leaves me hanging.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, I try to log on to iTunes on my iMac normally, and then it asks for the 6 digit verification code from another device.  Okay, no problem.  I retrieve it, and when I come back to the Mac, there's no input screen to key in the verification codes.  It leaves me hanging.

Answer (score 3):

Got exactly the same problem today, e.g:

- have two-factor auth.
- tried login to icloud on some old macbook (OSX Lion - 10.7)
- on my iphone i got the code
- but on the macbook there are no input fields - e.g. impossible to enter the code - there is no place where.

More googling and I found this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915 where says:

> What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older
> software?
>
> If you use two-factor authentication with devices running
> older OS versions—like an Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation)—you might
> be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your
> password when signing in. [Get your verification code](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974) from a trusted
> device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have
> it sent to your trusted phone number. **Then type your password followed
> by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.**

So, in short: if you didn't get the input fields, do the following:

- on the trusted device "Get the verification code" [how - see this](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974)
- and on the device without input fields enter your password, immediatelly followed by the 6 digit code - e.g. "MyPassord123456"

That's all - it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Apple ID's account security type is requesting verification (Two Factor Authentication). While this issues is primarily a software issue, If you want to cancel the security codes all together then you can switch the security type from Two Factor Authentication to Secondary Authentication where you'll need to know the security questions and your password to access your account. You can change that at: http://www.appleid.apple.com

Comment: I'd like to just simply turn OFF the Two-Factor Authentication altogether and just simply use the log-in ID and password concept like we have been before.    Oh, sure I understand the idea behind the Two-Factor concept but it has been a total nightmare since it installed itself at the last OS update.   My Apple experience has not been kind since.  I've lost count how many times I've had to reset my passwords. :-(                           So, HOW do I turn off the Two-Factor Authentication, completely, and revert back to the simply Log-in ID/password?

Comment: Go to http://www.appleid.apple.com and sign in to your account. Once you are in, go under security -> Edit (far right) -> Turn Off Two Factor Verification.

Comment: I BELIEVE I got it now.  Thank you.  So, now I need to play around the system to see if all the kinks worked out.    Since I've changed my passwords so many times, I hope I can keep 'em straight.                             Thank you again.  If I have any more issues, I'll be back.     Thanks again and have a good evening.

Comment: You're welcome! Your Apple Devices may ask you to sign in under settings since it noticed that you changed your security type of your account. All you need to do is sign in as usual. @AppleiMacVa-user