# Cannot access support.apple.com or update my OS

Tags: macos, network, safari, software-update, mac-appstore

I formatted my Late 2013 MacBook Pro, and now I have OS 10.9.5 (Mavericks) installed on it. I would like to update to the latest possible OS, but App Store is not giving me any updates.

I'm suspicious this has something to do with the fact that I can't access anything on the subdomain https://support.apple.com. I'm getting a "Safari can't establish a secure connection".

Do you have any tips on solving / troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: That sounds like your SSL certs expired.  macOS versions are generally supported with bug fixes for 2 or 3 years after the release of the next major release.  Security updates for another couple/three years.   It’s a 10 year old OS meaning its EOL.

Comment: Tom - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos & check not just the first answer but also those from David Anderson lower down. He has some very good solutions for older Macs [he also maintains the maclinks.publicvm.com site mentioned in the first answer. As pointed out in the comment above [which I'm now going to delete] older OS X has difficulty with modern https links & also being able to connect to the Apple Store properly.

Comment: @Allan - there are workarounds, using http.

Comment: @Allan, I'm on a late 2013 MacBook Pro and it is still getting security updates with Big Sur (the last update being just last month). So not necessarily end of life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you have downloaded and installed all the available updates for Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5). The latest possible macOS available for your Mac is Big Sur. Apple provides the website [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) which has the URL https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683. However if you use the version of Safari included with Mavericks to access this URL, you will instead get the following message.

[image]

A possible alternative would be to use the version of Safari included with Mavericks to access the website http://maclinks.publicvm.com. Here you will find links to the Apple App Store for High Sierra through Ventura. For example, the link for "Big Sur 11" will open the following App Store window.

[image: Big Sur]

If you have problems signing in to the App Store, then the question [No input fields for the Apple ID Verification for the iMac 10.10.5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304037/no-input-fields-for-the-apple-id-verification-for-the-imac-10-10-5) might provide some help.

I should also point out that [Tetsujin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400) comes with the following warning.

> *If you are trying to jump a long way - say from 10.8 to 10.14 or later, received wisdom is to first upgrade to El Capitan 10.11, then High Sierra 10.13.
>
> This will prepare your machine for the long jump.
>
> Some users seem to have managed to skip El Capitan, but High Sierra is still necessary, if it or newer has never been on the Mac before, as it adds a firmware update required to read the newer APFS filesystem.*

IMO, you might consider first upgrading to High Sierra, then upgrading to Big Sur. Although, when I tested in a virtual machine, I was able to upgrade from Maverick directly to Big Sur.